# HTML 5 drag events

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am trying to build a reorderable list in JS and HTML. (trying to do it without using jQuery ui ) I can't seem to figure out why only the dragstart and dragend events fire when a list item is dragged. Anyone know why the other events not firing?

```
<ul>
    <li draggable="true" class="drag">1111111</li>
    <li draggable="true" class="drag">222222</li>
    <li draggable="true" class="drag">333333</li>
    <li draggable="true" class="drag">444444</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var drags = document.querySelectorAll('.drag');
    [].forEach.call(drags, function(drag) {
      drag.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
      drag.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false);
      drag.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
      drag.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
      drag.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
    });

    function handleDragStart(e){
        console.log('handleDragStart');
    }

    function handleDragEnter(e){
        console.log('handleDragEnter');
    }

    function handleDragOver(e){
        console.log('handleDragOver');
    }

    function handleDragLeave(e){
        console.log('handleDragLeave');
    }

    function handleDragEnd(e){
        console.log('handleDragEnd');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Find a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/68QJu/ In Chrome on windows it's working (shit lot of `handleDragOver` o.O) so test it in different browers?

Comment: I was testing on in Chrome on Snow Leopard. Maybe it's just an issue there. I'll check

Comment: Yes I've just tested it on Chrome 20 on OS X - jsut start and end events.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have mentioned it already works in Chrome.  In Firefox you need to set `dataTransfer` on `dragstart` and you need to do an `e.preventDefault()` to make elements valid drop targets.  After that [everything starts working](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/4H4E5/):

```js
var drags = document.querySelectorAll('.drag');
[].forEach.call(drags, function(drag) {
  drag.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
  drag.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false);
  drag.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
  drag.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
  drag.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
  drag.addEventListener('drop', handleDragEnd, false);
});

function handleDragStart(e) {
  console.log('dragstart ' + e.target.innerText);
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'This text may be dragged')
}

function handleDragEnter(e) {
  console.log('dragenter ' + e.target.innerText);
  e.preventDefault();
}

function handleDragOver(e) {
  console.log('dragover ' + e.target.innerText);
  e.preventDefault();
}

function handleDragLeave(e) {
  console.log('dragleave ' + e.target.innerText);
}

function handleDragEnd(e) {
  console.log('dragend ' + e.target.innerText);
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<div draggable="true" class="drag">AAAAAA</div>
<div draggable="true" class="drag">BBBBBB</div>
<div draggable="true" class="drag">CCCCCC</div>
<div draggable="true" class="drag">DDDDDD</div>
<div draggable="true" class="drag">EEEEEE</div>
```

Note: I also added a `drop` handler so that Firefox wouldn't try to load a URL when you drop something.

Answer (score -1):

Using IE 10 works fine.

I recommend using jQuery UI, it's very, very simple and works in all browsers: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of this but was interested in how to getting working without jQuery - sorry should have mentioned that

Comment: this demo doesn't work with Touch (but that's jQuerys draggable fault). There are workarounds to make it work, sadly, it's a bit laggy then.