# HTML5 Dragend event didn't fire in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I am making some changes on drag start and want to revert them if drop fails. I wrote this logic in a function triggered by **dragend**. This works perfect in **Chrome** but in **firefox** 'Dragend' event is not fired.

Can anyone tell me something about this behaviour? I am using firefox 22.0 on ubantu.

Code is as below

```
    $(".view-controller").on("dragover", that.dragOverMain);
    $(".view-controller").on("dragenter", that.dragEnterMain); 
    $(".view-controller").on("dragexit dragleave", that.dragExitMain);
    $(".view-controller").on("dragend", that.dragEndMain);       
    $(".view-controller").on("drop", that.dropMain);

    $(".view-controller").children().on("dragstart", function(e) {
        that.dragStartChild(e);
    });
    $(".view-controller").children().on("dragend", function(e) {
        that.dragEndMain(e);
    }); 

    dragStartChild: function(e) { console.log('dragStartChild'); },
    dragEndMain: function(e) { console.log('dragEndMain'); e.preventDefault(); },
    dropMain: function(e) { console.log('dropMain'); e.preventDefault(); },
    dragExitMain: function(e) { console.log('dragExitMain'); e.preventDefault(); },
    dragEnterMain: function(e) { console.log('dragEnterMain'); e.preventDefault(); },
    dragOverMain: function(e) { console.log('dragOverMain'); e.preventDefault(); },
```

Comment: Maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11531582/1414562  BTW, why not providing your relevant code? A jsfiddle would be nice...

Comment: Thanks Roasted but I already have applied prevent Default and its not calling, it might be something else I have edited the code in this

Comment: Also noticed that esc key cancels drag in mozila but can't in chrome

Comment: At least change your `ev.preventDefault();` to `e.preventDefault();` since you name your event variable `e`.

Comment: This is a psuedo code as in regular function i have taken a diffrent variable ev which holds either the event as in mozila and e.orignalevent in others

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18269677/drag-and-drop-not-working-in-firefox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead.

```
<div ondragend="dragEndMain(event)" class="viewcontroller">
<!-- some html -->
</div>
```

Basically bind the javascript event in html itself.

Answer (score 9):

Firefox requires *drag data* to be set (`event.dataTransfer.setData(...)`) in the `dragstart` event. Without setting this data the `dragstart` event will fire, but the `dragend` event won't.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/Drag_operations#dragstart:

> To make another HTML element draggable, three things must be done:
>
> 1. Set the draggable attribute to true on the element that you wish to make draggable.
> 2. Add a listener for the dragstart event
> 3. Set the drag data within the listener defined above.

**Example:**

```
<div draggable="true" ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'This text may be dragged')">
  This text <strong>may</strong> be dragged.
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Worth adding here that Firefox has a bug that causes dragend to not fire if you're moving or deleting DOM elements as a part of your Drag and Drop functionality.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=460801

Moving the DOM manipulations into my method called on dragend solved this problem for me.